# Sylver Coinage Game

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

A game in which the players alternately name positive integers that
are not sums of previously named integers (with repetitions being allowed). The person who names 1 (so
ending the game) is the loser.

The question is: If player 1 names ‘16’, and both players play optimally thereafter, then who wins?

It has been known that if player 1 name "5n," then player 1 wins. If player name "5n+2", the result is known(maybe palyer 2 wins, but I haven't found the source yet). 16 is the minimum number of "5n+1".

I guess that this problem is PSPACE-hard, but I haven't proved it yet.

Comment: Apparently it's open whether Sylver Coinage is _decidable_.  Cool.  And at least as of 2002, [even Conway didn't know](http://archive.msri.org/communications/books/Book42/files/conway.pdf) who wins from 16.

Comment: Is it even efficient (i.e P time) to check if someone has lost ? Seems like the "you lost" test is an unbounded knapsack problem.

Comment: I am considering using the construction of sum-free set, for example, the set of odd numbers is a sum-free subset of the integers, and the set $\{N/2+1, ..., N\}$ forms a large sum-free subset of the set $\{1,...,N\}$ ($N$ even). Fermat's Last Theorem is the statement that the set of all nonzero nth powers is a sum-free subset of the integers for $n > 2$.However, some basic problems of sum-free set are still unknown. How many sum-free subsets of $\{1, ..., N\}$ are there, for an integer $N$? Ben Green has shown that the answer is $O(2^{N/2})$. Can this help?

Comment: @SureshVenkat It is efficient. For example, if the current coins are $4$, $5$, and $7$, you effectively have a regex of `(aaaa)*(aaaaa)*(aaaaaaa)*`, which can be matched against efficiently.

Comment: @PyRulez just writing down that regex is exponential time. However, there's an easy polynomial time test for whether you have to name 1 as your next move (and lose): it's true iff both 2 and 3 have already been named (and 1 hasn't). For if they have, then no higher numbers are available, and if they haven't, then one of those two numbers can be named next.

Comment: Here's an [updated link](http://library.msri.org/books/Book42/files/conway.pdf) for Jeffε's comment (as of May 2017).  Although I read Conway's comment as suggesting the problem is decidable: *"Is there an algorithm for Sylver Coinage that tells you, by looking over all (possibly infinite) options, what the status of the a position is and what if any are the winning moves? The answer is yes (see Winning Ways) but I do not know what the algorithm is."*

Comment: @NealYoung The algorithm in *Winning Ways* only gives whether an *opening move* is winning or not -- in accordance with Conway's comment, it relies on a theorem saying finitely moves of the form 2^a 3^b win, and I imagine (Conway having told me of that fact before) that this is what he meant when he said that an algorithm exists. If so, he was being unclear; however, this means that Jeffe's original comment was still correct.